# Core Data synthesize category instead of class, why?

Tags: ios, core-data

When synthesizing `Core Data` entity, it creates a not a class like `MyEntity.h .m`, but `MyEntity+CoreDataEntities.h .m`. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes that has been new in Xcode 7. When you create a managed object subclass, the Xcode creates 2 classes and one of them is a category class (className + CoreDataEntities). You better implement your custom methods in className.m and .h files.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, the model file generated by Xcode was "the" model file that many users wanted to use as their model class definition.  However, the Xcode generator would wipe out any contents of that file if you regenerated your model code.

If you couldn't recover from a source code version control system, your code was gone.

Xcode now tries to isolate the code it generates from code that you may have written for your entity class.

It will still overwrite the file it generates, but the way it does the process now means that users can use the logical approach of defining their class, and the file generated by Xcode should not interfere.

FWIW, this is explained in the WWDC 2015 core data presentation.

If you do anything at all with core data, I highly recommend keeping up with the WWDC presentations.  They are always full of very valuable information... and ALWAYS the first ones I watch every year.